# PostgreSQL ERROR: set-returning functions must appear at top level of FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I've got a postgres database in which I've got a `jsonb` field called `details`:

```
sensor | details
------------------
A      | [{"direction":"up", "result": 1.0}, {"direction":"up", "result": 2.0}]
B      | [{"direction":"up", "result": 3.0}, {"direction":"down", "result": 4.0}]
B      | [{"direction":"up", "result": 5.0}, {"direction":"up", "result": 6.0}, {"direction":"down", "result": 7.0}]
A      | [{"direction":"down", "result": 8.0}, {"direction":"left", "result": 9.0}]
```

I now need a sum of the `result` of all the up records and down records grouped by sensor.

So my query should result in this:

```
sensor | up_sum | down_sum
---------------------------
A      | 3.0      | 8.0
B      | 14.0     | 11.0
```

I need to somehow:

1. loop over the details array objects
2. filter by `up` and `down`
3. and then sum the results for those records per sensor

I guess subqueries are the only way to do this (correct?). I found [the postgres documentation on how to handle json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html), so I started to loop over the objects:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(details)
FROM table;
```

That simply gives me a list of the objects. So I now need to filter by `up` for which I think I need to use `json_to_recordset()`. I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM json_to_recordset('[{"direction":"up", "result": 1.0}, {"direction":"up", "result": 2.0}, {"direction":"down", "result": 3.0}]') as x(direction varchar, result float)
WHERE direction = 'up';
```

which results in the expected

```
direction | result
------------------
up        | 1
up        | 2
```

Now let's sum them:

```
SELECT SUM(result) as up_sum
FROM json_to_recordset('[{"direction":"up", "result": 1.0}, {"direction":"up", "result": 2.0}, {"direction":"down", "result": 3.0}]') as x(direction varchar, result float)
WHERE direction = 'up';
```

Great, that works!

Now I inserted that into my previous query:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_array_elements(details),
    (
        SELECT SUM(result)
        FROM json_to_recordset('[{"direction":"up", "result": 1.0}, {"direction":"up", "result": 2.0}, {"direction":"down", "result": 3.0}]') as x(direction varchar, result float)
        WHERE direction = 'up'
    ) as up_sum
FROM table;
```

Ok, that also works great.

Now I just need to use the result of `jsonb_array_elements(details)` in the `json_to_recordset()` (or actualy `jsonb_to_recordset()` for the `jsonb` field). So I then ran this:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_array_elements(details),
    (
        SELECT SUM(result)
        FROM jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_array_elements(details)) as x(direction varchar, result float)
        WHERE direction = 'up'
    ) as up_sum
FROM table;
```

Unfortunately that gives an error:

> ERROR: set-returning functions must appear at top level of FROM

Could anybody hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Your "inserted that into my previous" query does not work. It there a comma missing? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66b11e48f004b072d92e5ed641798fa2

Comment: @S-Man - Good point. I corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of your way is not quite clear to me. It seems very complicated.

But: The error you get: Because `jsonb_array_elements()` does not return just one single but many (a set of records, so, it is a "set-returning function"). A set of records cannot be used as an argument for another function directly. This is meant by "at the top level". Such a function can only appear directly as `FROM` list element.

---

Beside this: Here is the way I would chose to achieve your result:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c644f652c027b2600a06ff28cde64068)

Getting only the `up` sums:

```
SELECT 
    sensor,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric) AS up_sum    -- 3
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(details) elems             -- 1
WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'up'                  -- 2
GROUP BY sensor
```

1. Expand the array elements into one row each
2. Filter these elements by the `direction` value
3. SUM the `result` values

If you want to get the sums of both direction, you could use the conditional aggregations using the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT 
    sensor,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric)
        FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'up') AS up_sum,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric) 
        FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'down') AS down_sum
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(details) elems
GROUP BY sensor
```

Comment: This is an awesome anwser. It took me some time to comprehend it, but I do now. One more question, I also want the 50th percentile of the `up` elements. I found the `percentile_disc()` function for that. But I'm not sure how to use it on `elems`. Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure what result you are expecting (does this help in any way? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dd9e21bdce67ba6490f9387b309e4ca5)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below script

```
select a."sensor",(a."Result"->> 'direction')::character varying as "Direction",sum((a."Result"->> 'result')::float)::integer as "Result" from (
SELECT "sensor",jsonb_array_elements("details"::jsonb) "Result" FROM "A_Test1212"
) a
group by a."sensor",(a."Result"->> 'direction')::character varying 
order by a."sensor"

'A';'up';3
'A';'left';9
'A';'down';8
'B';'up';14
'B';'down';11
```

-- Pivot script

```
select * from crosstab(
'select a."sensor",(a."Result"->> ''direction'')::character varying as "Direction",sum((a."Result"->> ''result'')::float)::integer as "Result" from (
SELECT "sensor",jsonb_array_elements("details"::jsonb) "Result" FROM "A_Test1212"
) a
group by "sensor",(a."Result"->> ''direction'')::character varying
order by a."sensor"') as finalresult("sensor" character varying,"up" integer,"down" integer,"left" integer);


'A';3;9;8
'B';14;11;<NULL>
```