# How to show count of single table when using FROM two tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a postgres database in which I've got a `jsonb` field called `details`:

```
timestamp              | sensor | details
-------------------------------------------
2018-10-10 08:00:00+01 | A      | [{"result": 1.0, "direction": "up"}, {"result": 2.0, "direction": "up"}]
2018-10-10 09:01:00+01 | A      | [{"result": 1.0, "direction": "up"}, {"result": 2.0, "direction": "up"}]
2018-10-10 09:01:00+01 | B      | [{"result": 3.0, "direction": "up"}, {"result": 4.0, "direction": "down"}]
2018-10-10 09:01:00+01 | B      | [{"result": 5.0, "direction": "up"}, {"result": 6.0, "direction": "up"}, {"result": 7.0, "direction": "down"}]
2018-10-10 09:01:00+01 | A      | [{"result": 8.0, "direction": "down"}, {"result": 9.0, "direction": "left"}, {"result": 10.0, "direction": "down"}]
```

I had to sum up the `result` of all the `up` records and `down` records per 15 minutes and grouped by sensor.

So with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079130/1650012) I got to this query:

```
SELECT
    CASE -- round by every 15 minutes
        WHEN extract('minute' from timestamp) < 15 THEN date_trunc('hour', timestamp)
        WHEN extract('minute' from timestamp) < 30 THEN date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + '15 minutes'
        WHEN extract('minute' from timestamp) < 45 THEN date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + '30 minutes'
        ELSE date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + '45 minutes'
    END AS timestamp_rounded,
    sensor,
    SUM((detail_elems ->> 'result')::numeric) FILTER (WHERE detail_elems ->> 'direction' = 'up') AS up_sum,
    SUM((detail_elems ->> 'result')::numeric) FILTER (WHERE detail_elems ->> 'direction' = 'down') AS down_sum,
    count(sensor) as record_count
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(details) detail_elems
GROUP BY
    timestamp_rounded,
    sensor
ORDER BY 
    timestamp_rounded ASC,
    sensor ASC
;
```

Which results in this:

```
timestamp_rounded      | sensor | up_sum | down_sum | record_count
------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-10 08:00:00+01 | A      | 3.0    |          | 2  -- expected 1
2018-10-10 09:00:00+01 | A      | 3.0    | 18.0     | 5  -- expected 2
2018-10-10 09:00:00+01 | B      | 14.0   | 11.0     | 5  -- expected 2
```

The sums are correct, but unfortunately the `record_count` is incorrect. I expect it to show the count of the records from the original table that are used per line. Instead, it shows the number of records from the `details` field that are used for that line. I added a comment behind it to show what numbers I expect.

Does anybody know why I get the records in the `detail_elems` instead of the `mytable`?

[EDIT]

So I now have it working, but with a Subquery (yikes!):

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT
    *,
    CASE -- round by every 15 minutes
        WHEN extract('minute' from timestamp) < 15 THEN date_trunc('hour', timestamp)
        WHEN extract('minute' from timestamp) < 30 THEN date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + '15 minutes'
        WHEN extract('minute' from timestamp) < 45 THEN date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + '30 minutes'
        ELSE date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + '45 minutes'
    END AS timestamp_rounded
FROM
    mytable
)
SELECT 
    timestamp_rounded,
    sensor,
    SUM((detail_elems ->> 'result')::numeric) FILTER (WHERE detail_elems ->> 'direction' = 'up') AS up_sum,
    SUM((detail_elems ->> 'result')::numeric) FILTER (WHERE detail_elems ->> 'direction' = 'down') AS down_sum,
    (SELECT count(*) from tmp tmp2 where tmp2.timestamp_rounded=tmp.timestamp_rounded and tmp2.sensor=tmp.sensor) as record_count_correct
    -- COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor, extract(year from timestamp_rounded), extract(month from timestamp_rounded), extract(day from timestamp_rounded), extract(hour from timestamp_rounded), extract(minute from timestamp_rounded)) AS record_count_incorrect
FROM 
    tmp,
    jsonb_array_elements(details) detail_elems
GROUP BY
    timestamp_rounded,
    sensor
ORDER BY 
    timestamp_rounded ASC,
    sensor ASC
```

This works, but unfortunately it is very slow (10 minutes on an export from our production database running on my laptop). I did some profiling and the subquery is clearly the problem (without it, it takes about 6 seconds).

So I tried it using the `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY` pattern (also in the query above) in which I use the `sensor` and the `timestamp` to partition by, but that gives incorrect results.

Here's a fiddle of my current state: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=65074f510de678b2a60255483bdb0be4

Any ideas how to correctly implement the PARTITION BY in this current state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2f826fa701ca50cd306348ae1a31773b)

Because you want to count the records of the original, unexpanded version, you should do the count first (e.g. in a subquery using a `COUNT()` window function)

```
SELECT 
    sensor,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric)
        FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'up') AS up_sum,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric) 
        FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'down') AS down_sum,
    cnt
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor) AS cnt
    FROM
        mytable   
    )s,
    jsonb_array_elements(details) elems
GROUP BY sensor, cnt
```

---

**Edit: Question added time slots.**

So, the timeslots can be used for creating partitions:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=16d79850b47a8d32754651e41f37c4bc)

```
SELECT 
    sensor,
    to_timestamp(time_slot * 60 * 15) as time_slot,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric)
        FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'up') AS up_sum,
    SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric) 
        FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'down') AS down_sum,
    cnt
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        EXTRACT(epoch from "timestamp")::int / 60 / 15 as time_slot,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(epoch from "timestamp")::int / 60 / 15, sensor) AS cnt
    FROM
        mytable   
    )s,
    jsonb_array_elements(details) elems
GROUP BY sensor, time_slot, cnt
```

Comment: Hi S-Man. It took me some time to fully comprehend what was going on and to fit it in the larger (humongous) query I have. But I succeeded and it works perfect! The dbfiddle thing is really great by the way! I'm now using it more as well. Thanks!

Comment: @kramer65 Thanks for upvote. I would appreciate if you could accept the answer as well to close it. :)

Comment: Ok, in the end it didn't work out. Simply because I didn't test enough and I didn't give you the full picture. The thing is that I also need to PARTITION BY the date which I group per 15 minutes. I got it working with a subquery, but that is very slow. And I can't get PARTITION BY working with the rounded timestamp either. I rewrote the question with some more elaborate examples and I added a fiddle. I understand that it kinda became a different question, but it would be really awesome if you could have another short look.

Comment: Works like a charm, and cut the query time on production data from 10 minutes to 6 seconds; awesome! Indeed, you solved it twice, plus I learned a lot on the way. You made my week!

Answer (score 1):

you get 5 and 5 by sensor because when you write :

```
FROM
mytable,
jsonb_array_elements(details) elems
```

and get the Cartesian product from both tables :

```
SELECT 
sensor,
elems.*
FROM
mytable,
jsonb_array_elements(details) elems; --5 and 5 by sensor

"A";"{"result": 1.0, "direction": "up"}"
"A";"{"result": 2.0, "direction": "up"}"
"B";"{"result": 3.0, "direction": "up"}"
"B";"{"result": 4.0, "direction": "down"}"
"B";"{"result": 5.0, "direction": "up"}"
"B";"{"result": 6.0, "direction": "up"}"
"B";"{"result": 7.0, "direction": "down"}"
"A";"{"result": 8.0, "direction": "down"}"
"A";"{"result": 9.0, "direction": "left"}"
"A";"{"result": 10.0, "direction": "down"}"
```

you can write your query with a subquery like this :

```
SELECT 
sensor,
SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric)
    FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'up') AS up_sum,
SUM((elems ->> 'result')::numeric) 
    FILTER (WHERE elems ->> 'direction' = 'down') AS down_sum,
     (select count (*) from mytable i_myt where i_myt.sensor=mytable.sensor )  
     as record_count   --subquery to count

 FROM
mytable,
jsonb_array_elements(details) elems
GROUP BY sensor;



"B";14.0;11.0;2
"A";3.0;18.0;2
```

Comment: I did this, and it works, but unfortunately it's way too slow. Any ideas how to rewrite it so that it is more performant?

Comment: you can add index in sensor column or use WITH clause where you can calculate the record_count , do you had use WITH clause sometime?