# Average of numeric values in Postgres JSON column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `jsonb` column with the following structure:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "type": "...",
        "label": "...",
        "variables": [
            {
                "label": "Height",
                "value": 131315.9289,
                "variable": "myVar1"
            },
            {
                "label": "Width",
                "value": 61085.7525,
                "variable": "myVar2"
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

I want to query for the average height across all rows. The top-level key values are unknown, so I have something like this:

```
select id,
       avg((latVars ->> 'value')::numeric) as avg
from "MyTable",
    jsonb_array_elements((my_json_field->jsonb_object_keys(my_json_field)->>'variables')::jsonb) as latVars
where my_json_field is not null
group by id;
```

It's throwing the following error:
`ERROR: set-returning functions must appear at top level of FROM`

Moving the `jsonb_array_elements` function above `MyTable` in the FROM clause doesn't work.

I'm following the basic advice found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079130) to no avail.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonb_array_elements` is not relevant until `my_json_field` is a json array at the top level.

You can use instead the `jsonb_path_query` function based on the [jsonpath language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) if postgres >= 12 :

```
select id
     , avg(v.value :: numeric) as avg
from "MyTable"
   , jsonb_path_query(my_json_field, '$.*.variables[*] ? (@.label == "Height").value') AS v(value)
where my_json_field is not null
group by id;
```